# Mapping variables between the visual studio and PLC device

Tags: c#

I have developed one application in visual studio c# and I'm connecting my application with the PLC device. I'm able to read the value from PLC to visual studio but I'm unable to do the  reverse Process.
the way to connect PLC and visual studio is

```
/************************/

/* Connection TcpIp */

/************************/

cpu.Connection.DeviceType = BR.AN.PviServices.DeviceType.TcpIp;

cpu.Connection.TcpIp.SourceStation = 1;

cpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationStation = 2;

cpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationIpAddress = "10.43.70.202";
```

Comment: Write more details. Which type of PLC?

Comment: Visual studio doesn't open ports or do anything much apart from compile and run software

Comment: B&R PLC 4PP065.0571-X74F using PVI transfer method

Comment: Hi Saruman, Thank you for response. Can I know what do you mean by open ports??